# RepositoryLookUpEdit display meber show on grid control (footer)

Tags: c#, vb.net, devexpress

I have grid control with three columns, one of them is a lookUpEdit control. In the cell I display its **value member** and this works fine. But I also want to display the **display member** to footer grid control something like information text.

If I choose different values ??in my control **RepositoryLookUpEdit** then I want to display its corresponding text value (displayMember) to footer of the grid control. My code goes like this:

```
Dim edit As RepositoryItemLookUpEdit = New RepositoryItemLookUpEdit
edit.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
edit.DisplayMember = ds.Tables(0).Columns("KONTOSIFRA").Caption.ToString
edit.ValueMember = ds.Tables(0).Columns("KONTOSIFRA").Caption.ToString
edit.SearchMode = SearchMode.AutoFilter

' ds.Tables(0).Columns("KONTONAZIV").Caption.ToString   ' This is what I want to show (display member)

dgvControl.RepositoryItems.Add((edit))

With dgView
    .Columns(1).Name = "KONTOSIFRA"
    .Columns(1).FieldName = "KONTOSIFRA"
    .Columns(1).Caption = "KONTO"
    .Columns(1).ColumnEdit = edit
    .Columns(1).DisplayFormat.FormatType = FormatType.Numeric
    .Columns(1).DisplayFormat.FormatString = "n"
    .Columns(1).OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = True
    .Columns(1).SummaryItem.SummaryType = DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Custom
    .Columns(1).SummaryItem.DisplayFormat =  ' Here I need to insert display member...?


    Dim test As System.Data.DataRowView
    test = edit.Properties.GetRowByKeyValue(edit.EditValue)
    .Columns(1).SummaryItem.DisplayFormat = test.Item(1).ToString ' This works for gridLookUpEdit control, but my control is RepositoryLookUpEdit. How do I the same thing, only for my control?
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`RepositoryItemLookUpEdit.GetDisplayValueByKeyValue`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemLookUpEdit_GetDisplayValueByKeyValuetopic) method to get the **display member** from known **value member**. And you need to handle [`GridView.CustomSummaryCalculate`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomSummaryCalculatetopic) event.
Here is example:

```
Private values As List(Of String)

Private Sub dgView_CustomSummaryCalculate(sender As Object, e As CustomSummaryEventArgs) Handles gridView1.CustomSummaryCalculate

    If Not e.IsTotalSummary Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Const fieldName$ = "KONTOSIFRA"

    Dim summaryItem As GridSummaryItem = TryCast(e.Item, GridSummaryItem)

    If summaryItem Is Nothing AndAlso summaryItem.FieldName <> fieldName$ Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Select Case e.SummaryProcess
        Case CustomSummaryProcess.Start
            values = New List(Of String)
        Case CustomSummaryProcess.Calculate
            Dim edit As RepositoryItemLookUpEdit = DirectCast(dgView.Columns(fieldName$).ColumnEdit, RepositoryItemLookUpEdit)
            Dim value As Object = edit.GetDisplayValueByKeyValue(e.FieldValue)

            If Not IsNothing(value) Then
                values.Add(value)
            End If
        Case CustomSummaryProcess.Finalize
            If values.Count > 0 Then
                e.TotalValue = String.Join(", ", values.Distinct())
            End If
    End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
.Columns(1).SummaryItem.DisplayFormat = "MyCustValue"
```

Since you've set the `SummaryType` to `Custom`, you need to handle `CustomSummaryCalculate` event.

In this event you do this:

```
if (e.SummaryProcess == CustomSummaryProcess.Finalize) {
  var item = e.Item as GridColumnSummaryItem;
  if (item.FieldName == "KONTOSIFRA") {
    e.TotalValue = "blahblah";
  }
}
```

Comment: I have no problem how to display text . I know that. What I want is to display the text of the second column of my lookUpEdit control that will depend on the choice of the values ​​in the first column

Comment: Hence handling of CustomSummaryCalculate event.

Comment: Did you see my edit? Ok but how to get to these values => "blahblah"

Comment: Is your question really "How do I get displayed text in LookupEdit"? 
var text = edit.GetDisplayText(edit.EditValue);

Comment: Yes, but on grid control footer. On my choice to display the text in the footer. If i select second row I want to see on my gridControl footer text of second column. Actually my control is not just LookupEdit, it is RepositoryLookUpEdit and that control dose not have .editvalue

Comment: Get the value from the focused datarow.
var text = edit.GetDisplayText(dgView.GetFocusedDataRow(["KONTOSIFRA"]));